# Bootstrap CSS table row height with dropdown button too large

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap table where the rows are too high when I use button dropdowns.  Is there some CSS I can use to stop this happening ?

I've noticed that Bootstrap's tables with normal buttons are not 100% perfect: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables but they're better than what's happening with my dropdown buttons.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uEMtf/

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>some stuff</td><td>some more stuff</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>here's something</td>
            <td><div class="btn-toolbar"><div class="btn-group"> <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options<span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> <li><a href="del"> Action 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="details"> Action 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="edit"> Action 2</a></li></ul></div></div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>here's something</td>
            <td><button class="btn" href="#">Default</button></td>
                    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>another row</td>
            <td>with more stuff</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: .btn-toolbar class has margin-top & margin-bottom 9px. remove that & it will work.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/uEMtf/1/

Comment: @VCS it would prob be better just to remove the `btn-toolbar` class off the element rather than override it. Apart from that, this should be an answer rather than a comment ;)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts ha ha ha...its SVS..ya it should be an answer if it helps the person who asked the question.

Comment: @SVS hah, sorry - having a dyslexic morning! Think I'll go get another coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class `.btn-toolbar` class or define margin top & bottom zero somewhere in your css code below `.btn-toolbar` class

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/uEMtf/1/